# Laravel 6 allow "null" to be passed on route parameter

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and upgrading to Laravel 6.0.
There are numerous codes that goes like this in the project:

```
 route('some_route_name', optional($someobject)->id)
```

Laravel 5.5 can have `null` passed on that route above and not throwing an error.
Now it returns this error below because most of the time the value is `null`

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: some_route_name]
```

Now I have to replace all occurrences of the code above with:

```
 route('some_route_name', optional($someobject)->id ?: 0)
```

Is there any way to accept "null" as route parameters?
Or maybe this is bad practice in general?

Comment: show your route file for this route ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply, in your route just put one question mark

```
route('some_route_name/{id?}','Controller@show');
```

Then in your controller

```
public function show($id = null)
```

Or if you bind with the Model, change your route to

```
route('some_route_name/{user?}','Controller@show');
```

And your controller will be like this

```
 public function show(User $user)
```